# Is there any substitute for ifnull()

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, ejb, ejbql

I have a query for mysql where ifnull() is used.i want to convert it into ejb-ql. Problem here is that i dont find any substitute equivalent to ifnull() in ejb.

For eg:

```
ifnull(columnname,' ') as newcoulmn
```

Comment: May be `coalesce(columnname,' ') as newcoulmn` that's widely supported construction

Comment: Yes, this should be the soultion - `coalesce(columnname,' ')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
  coalesce(columnname, ' ') as newcolumn
```

since `coalesce` is widely supported function when `ifnull` is MySql *specific* one

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try this and update u with the results asap.